# How to subtract an absolute value from both sides of an inequality? ($y+|x|<3$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I have been trying to find an example online, but I can't.

If I had an equation like:

$$y + |x| < 3$$

and I wanted to graph it, I know that to get it to slope intercept form I need to isolate the $y$.

**How do I subtract the $x$ though?**

Does it become $-|x|$ on the right side or does it become $|-x|$?

Comment: Well, you do not have an equation but an inequality. Also, you would subtract $|x|$ from *both* sides, resulting in $y<-|x|+3$. What does this mean? Probably the most effective way to think about this is transformations. You probably know what the graph of $|x|$ looks like. What does the graph of $-|x|$ look like? Once you have that, *shift* it all up by 3 units. Since $y$ is less than $-|x|+3$ ... what does that mean?

Comment: Do you know how to graph $y+x<3$?  Do you know how to graph $y-x<3$?  Note that $y+|x|=\begin{cases} y+x&\text{if}~x\geq 0\\ y-x&\text{if}~x<0\end{cases}$

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I think the original title was OK, but your title did not summarize what was actually being asked, so I reverted to something closer to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

$$y+|x| < 3$$
Subtracting $|x|$ from both sides, we have
$$y+|x|-|x| < 3-|x|$$
Since $|x|-|x|=0$,

$$y < 3-|x|$$

That is for $x \geq 0$, plot $y <3-x$.

For $x<0$, plot $y < 3+x$.

@Daniel_W._Farlow's approach based on transformation is awesome.

Comment: *Words* would help this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should think of "$|x|$" as a *number,* just like any other number: $3$, or $x$, or $(x + 5)$, or $10$. These are all numbers. You are allowed subtract any *number* from both sides of an inequality.

In this case, we have
$$
y + |x| < 3
$$
and we have to subtract the same number from both sides, so we subtract "$|x|$" from both sides:
$$
y + |x| - |x| < 3 - |x|
$$
to arrive at
$$
y < 3 - |x|.
$$